# How to handle multiple uploads and save in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, cakephp-2.0

I'm using CakePHP 2.0.6 and have a form with a input of type field and multiple property setup to multiple to upload more than one file. I have also a table (called document) where I need to save the name and route of uploaded files. This table is related to other (called information) as a 1:m relationship so when I saveAll() in information must save all the uploaded files in document too. How I can achieve this? Any help or tips? Can I handle first the upload and then save the data? How?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Well I try several tutorials and docs over the Internet but none seems to work or I'm doing something wrong. In first place I'm trying to use multiple INPUT from HTML5 but for unknow reason when I debug $this->request->data only one file is showed as Array in the file field but the others are gone. Then I think using jQuery clone the element but this give a lot of headaches so any help?

Comment: Do you read this? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/veganista/2012/01/31/html_5_multiple_file_upload_with_cake

Comment: There are a lot of plugins out there to upload files, but itś normal php programming. You could look into the MediaPlugin. Here is a tutorial: http://blog.creativeideal.net/cakephp/beautiful-html5-file-uploads-using-cakephp-and-jquery I think, its a great starting point

Comment: I've try that the HTML5 multiple but doesn't work and don't know why. I setup the field as multiple but when send the data and then check using debug($this->request->data) the Array of file input have only one value even if I select 2 o 3 files. Did you give a try with CakePHP? Maybe is my problem but I'm not so sure

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. read **[this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)**.

And Use ***DOT*** (.) at the end of file names. see blow starssss for example.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('type' => 'file')); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('***User.photo.***', array('type' => 'file','multiple'=>'multiple')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('User.photo_dir', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('submit'); ?>
```